# Specify the timeout of a java object

Tags: java, timeout

I would like to create an object that dies when its timeout is reached. How can I achieve this ?

For instance in pseudo code:

```
MyObject O = new MyObject(3000) ; // object created will be null after 3 seconds
wait(4000) ;
if (O == null)
  print("success") ;
```

Is it possible ?

## Edit :

Actually I'm using a large map of MyObjects. Each one should die after 1 min of its creation. Now I am thinking about adding a creationDate to MyObject and a method that would check my map of MyObject when its size becomes too large... and put null to the timeout objects references. That would be another approach considering the fact I don't need all objects to be null as soon as they should (ie, they should be null after 1 min but it's not so important as long as my map isn't huge).

Comment: Do you mean that invocation of constructor may take more than 4 seconds?

Comment: No I mean... I create an object that dies after 3 seconds.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "object dies"?

Comment: There is really not really a good solution to destroy Java object from within itself. Could you maybe work around this limitation by using a nullable field or a boolean value?

Comment: If you don't mind the performance hit; by far the easiest way to do this is to check the elapsed time every method call and if its too old then take appropriate action (probably throwing an exception). I can't think of a way to go after every (potentially huge number) reference. Or do you just want that one variable to be null? That is easier

Comment: Actually I'm using a large map of MyObjects. Each one should die after 1 min of its creation. Now I am thinking about adding a creationDate to MyObject and a method that would check my map of MyObject when its size becomes too large... and put null to the timeout objects references. That would be another solution considering the fact I don't need all objects to be null as soon as they should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to 'kill' an object at a certain point in a program, you can just assign the variable to `null` and the garbage collection will do it automatically.

```
// Make MyObject
MyObject O = new MyObject(3000);
// Wait 4 seconds
wait(4000);
// 'delete' it, the object made with `new MyObject(4000)` cannot be used anymore.
O = null;
```

Comment: Used this simple fact because it occurred I didn't absolutely need a timer after all...

Answer (score 1):

You should create `ExecutorService` and submit there new `Runnable` task. It will return you an instance of `Future`, on which you could do wating for needed time.

```
    Runnable task = new Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           // do your job
           // or just:
           MyObject O = new MyObject(3000);
           // some job on O object
        }
    };
    Future<?> future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(task);
    try {
        return future.get(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);            
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit

Perhaps what would fit your needs the best is a cache. Consider [Guava's Cache](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained). A Cache can have a limited size (removing LRU elements as necessary), expire elements after a certain time, etc.

An example from their docs:

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
       .maximumSize(1000)
       .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
       .removalListener(MY_LISTENER)
       .build(
           new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
             public Graph load(Key key) throws AnyException {
               return createExpensiveGraph(key);
             }
           });
```

---

You could implement your own class similar to Java's [`Reference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html) implementations.

For example:

```java
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class TimeoutReference<T> {
    public final AtomicReference<T> reference;

    /**
     * Create new instance
     * @param referent The reference
     * @param timeout minimum length of time the reference is guaranteed to not
     * be {@code null}.
     * @param unit the units of {@code timeout}
     * @throws NullPointerException if any parameter is {@code null}.
     */
    public TimeoutReference(T reference, long timeout, TimeUnit unit) {
        this.reference = new AtomicReference<>(
                Objects.requireNonNull(reference));
        ScheduledExecutorService service
                = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        service.schedule(() -> {
                    this.referent.set(null);
                    service.shutdown();
                }, timeout, unit);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the reference or {@code null} if the time has expired.
     */
    public T get() { // perhaps throw a checked exception for clarity.
        return reference.get();
    }
}
```

Which seems to work reasonably well,

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // object created will be null after 3 seconds
    TimeoutReference<String> o = new TimeoutReference<>(
            "My non-null value", 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    System.out.println("Before: " + o.get());
    Thread.sleep(4000) ;
    System.out.println("After: " + o.get());
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Before: My non-null value
After: null
```

I would caution that a programming style where `null` as a correct use-case can be error prone.

Comment: Why do you not recommend it ?

Comment: @Lyth Sorry, I wasn't very clear before, let me explain. It's not `TimeoutReference` that I don't recommend, it's using `null`. In general, `null` can make programs more complex. A simple manifestation of that is `if (a != null)` checks everywhere in your code; which are messy. It can be done correctly, just be cautious.

Comment: How do you estimate the performance cost of such an implementation ?

Comment: @Lyth Do you mean the implementation of `TimeoutReference` or of `if(null)` checks? In general, *correctness* is more important than *performance*. Unless you're making a lot of `TimeoutReference` instances (maybe 1000s?), I think it should perform fine. In the `if(null)` case, it's performance is fine, but it makes your code messier. Make the code easier for humans, not the computer.

Comment: Yes I'm thinking about the performance when having like 200 TimeoutReference alive, doesn't it have a big impact on memory consumption (maybe "performance" wasnt the word) ? Please also check the edit of my post. I'm wondering what approach would be best.

Comment: @Lyth Perhaps you should use Guava's Cache instead.

Comment: Hello, I don't undertstand the example of  Guava's Cache. I hope to have a key-value structure that after several mins, when i get(key_which_is_timeout) , if it return null. For that example, it seems it will work, but return createExpensiveGraph(key) is not resolved said by the ide. Could you please also write an example of your own which can be executed?